# List of tables that leave traces in CDHDR and CDPOS tables

Tags: abap, hana, sap-erp, sap-cloud-connector

I want to capture changes for all possible SAP tables.

I figured out that `CDHDR` and `CDPOS` tables capture change documents but it's not clear for which all tables it does that.

I have multiple questions to ask:

1. Get list of all tables for which `CDHDR` and `CDPOS` tables capture
   change documents.
2. As `CDPOS` table only contains changed field and I need to map it with 
   Primary Key of the table. How can I map changed record with primary key 
   of a table?

Answer (score 3):

To purely answer your question, I certainly can tell you to look into the t-code `SCDO` to get the clue on what you need, but I would choose to challenge your reasoning approach. So, you have a requirement to capture changes for all possible SAP tables. For what purpose? There are thousands of SAP tables being tracked by `CDHDR` and `CDPOS`, and most tables there do not bring immediate business values to you. Whenever a table column has a data element like `BELNR_D` and `GJAHR`, it could appear in `CDHDR`, because such element is marked as "Change Document" flag (t-code `SE11`): [image]

And SAP's explanation to the flag is:

> The flag for change documents specifies whether changes to fields in database tables defined with reference to this data element are logged when change document objects are involved.

Therefore, with thousands of tables being tracked, it would not be a good idea to solve the problem purely from technical aspect, and we have not even started looking into the performance problem with `CDHDR` and `CDPOS` yet.

If your requirement is part of a data warehousing project, then without the hassle of dealing with `CDPOS` and `CDHDR`, you can analyze the incremental insertion, deletion and update through the transparent tables or standard extractors. If you can use DB trigger, then SLT could also be an option to get the changed records on the tables you are interested in at almost real-time (5-second delay by default setting).

To summarize, to get to what you need, you can navigate to SAP Menu - Tools - ABAP Workbench - Other Tools - Change Document, or simply the t-code `SCDO`. However, my comment above on the business requirement is what I really intend to express.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It’s my use case to capture changes for analytical purpose, i need to automate this process so i am using JDBC.
I have got few more doubts from your answer:
1. As you said there are flags like BELNR_D and GJAHR in tables that appear in CDHDR, how can i get list of all such flags? I don’t see these flags as part of columns for a table. 
2. Do i need to manually enable Change Document flag for tables or it’s is enabled by default?
3. Do you have any suggestions for mapping of records with primary key, that’s my 2nd query in original question?

Comment: When you use SE11 or SE12 to open table schema (e.g. BKPF), please look under the "Data element" column, and you will find that the elements like BELNR_D. You should not enable it or disable it manually. It's a system setting which tells you that the table could have changed records in CDHDR and CDPOS. If we still use Accounting Doc as example, from experience you would know its change document is BELE* like BELEG (which can be confirmed in SCDO). Then, in CDHDR, you use "BELEG" in OBJECTCLAS, to get the list of OBJECTID, with which you can filter with CDPOS to get the details of changes.

Comment: I still think you should look into the source table level incremental load. For example, if you deal with accounting document, the delta is already well tracked by extractor 0FI_GL_4 which is easier to use than BKPF/BSEG extract. For sales order, table is easier to access than logistics extractors. I wrote some topics on subject in the blog area on our company website.

Answer (score 1):

Why not running `SELECT DISTINCT tabname FROM cdpos` to get the actual list of all tables? I guess it should be sufficient because your SAP system has been live for a while. If you can't do it yourself, ask someone, once for all.

In the table `CDPOS`, you get the ID of the object changed from the column `TABKEY`. If the primary key is made of several columns, `TABKEY` is the concatenation of the character values, with the alignment based on each column size. I'm not sure, but I guess that the primary key columns (of tables referred by TABNAME of CDPOS) always have character types.

The columns of the primary key of one table can be extracted from the ABAP Dictionary with this SQL query: `SELECT fieldname, leng FROM dd03l WHERE tabname = 'one_table' AND fieldname LIKE '.%' AND keyflag = 'X' ORDER BY position` (column names starting with a dot are for internal stuff).

Comment: Sandra, your edit to my reply was appreciated! Just a small comment on the primary key data type: I did a search in DD03L table and found the primary key types can include non-character types like hexadecimal (x), string (g), floating point (F), as well as those common types like N, D, T which are actually characters in the underlying database.

Comment: @AecorSoft I meant [columns of tables referred by TABNAME of CDPOS] "always have character types". Answer updated.